# GPU render turning out grey when using certain materials

Tags: rendering, gpu

i'm trying to render a scene, but when i am using my GPU te render something, the end result gets a grey layer on top of the image.
the problem appeared after amd's crimson drivers or after blender 2.76

[image]

Like when using a bump map.

however when i'm rendering the scene with my cpu, it turns out normal.
[image]

Can someone please explain me why this is happening and/or how to solve this?

thanks for the effort, iron

Comment: If you use OSL shaders, I don't think they can run on the GPU.  What GPU are you using, maybe that one isn't fully supported yet?

Comment: This can be the cause of bad drivers. But also it can be the case of a bad graphics card. -> Bad memory EEC

Answer (score 2):

I'm using AMD R9 280 graphics card and I had the same problem.

Reverting to older AMD drivers seems to fix the problem. I reverted from the newest drivers to 16.4.2 version and Blender (2.77) rendering on GPU works again!

You can find older driver versions here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/previous?os=Windows%207%20-%2064

Maybe you can revert to a bit newer drivers and the Blender will still work, I don't know, haven't tested it. I'm just really glad the GPU rendering works again and hopefully AMD fixes this issue asap.

Cheers!