# Cycles OpenCL GPU Render Gray Overlay/Mist?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, opencl

Dear Blender Community,

Several weeks ago I suddenly experienced difficulty when rendering on my GPU.
Whereas before the renders looked just like the CPU renders as they are supposed to, my GPU renders now had a gray overlay or mist, if you will, in them.
This happens in every scenes, but I will illustrate the difference with pictures from the following test scene:
[image: A rendered image using CPU rendering (looking normal)] 
A rendered image using CPU rendering (looking normal)

[image: The same scene rendered by GPU]
The same scene rendered by GPU

For the GPU render I used OpenCL rendering, thus using an AMD graphics card.
The odd thing is that when I used GPU rendering in the viewport rendering the preview looked perfectly fine without any gray overlay.
I've already tried tweaking many settings, though nothing made any difference.
Except rendering with a very low sampling amount, like 5, made it so you have a very ugly grainy image though with very little of the gray overlay.

I really hope someone might have a solution for this problem so I will again be able to render scenes with shorter render time.
If any more information is required feel free to asked and thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to BSE, uploading your .blend file might help you get the right answer, you can upload your file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55204/gpu-render-turning-out-grey-when-using-certain-materials

Comment: Thank you, I don't think uploading the .blend file, will be of any use because the problem occurs in every blend file I use.
I've through the related linked problem though (Thanks a lot for the link) and I'm going to try downgrade my driver. If this remains with no result, I will upload my .blend file anyway.

Comment: i have the same problem ! i fixed it by selecting "progressive refine" under "performance" but it slows down the progress by x10 aprox... any sugestions ?

Comment: I had the same problem with amd 7870. Possible solution 1- luxrender. 2 -"Cycles" AMD Catalyst drivers "CRIMSON" change of version.
In any case I would be interested to know that CPU and GPU uses, in order to assist you better.

Comment: Cycles OpenCL support is still rather experimental.. Does this behavior persist in 2.78?

Comment: Hey Everyone, thanks for all the help you've offered. My problem has been solved. The latest update for my gpu fixed the problem.