# GPU rendering result is a white image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

So I just found out how to fix the GPU rendering error I encountered (check the answer that I got in my question about fixing the error: [Rendering with AMD Radeon R5 M330 gives an error that I can't understand!](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68148/rendering-with-amd-radeon-r5-m330-gives-an-error-that-i-cant-understand))
and when I tried to render with GPU I got a white image as the result.
Here is the Scene rendered with CPU (good result) and rendered with GPU (White Image):
[image: CPU rendering result]

[image: GPU rendering result]

I couldn't find the problem here.
The settings are exactly the same for both renders (except for the rendering device of course)

Comment: Do you have any post processing? It looks like a bad mist pass or similar. The elements are all there if you look closely, and the image is **not** just white.

Comment: Maybe related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55819/cycles-opencl-gpu-render-gray-overlay-mist and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55204/gpu-render-turning-out-grey-when-using-certain-materials. AMDs can lack some features, see https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/features.html

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ Yes it is not plain white I noticed that.

Comment: @MrZak wow AMD GPUs lack a lot of features in blender! I guess I have nothing to do other than render with the CPU again. I was really excited about speeding up my renders with GPU Rendering but when I saw that table at the site u told me to see I found out that a lot of features that i'm using/planning to use are not supported by AMD GPUs . *depression*

Comment: Some of them can be added after some time.. After all, smoke+fire couldn't be rendered on Nvidia not so long ago too but not now. For now I suggest render all heavy data like meshes etc. on GPU and save to EXR; all the unsupported features on CPU and save as well; if using transparency correctly everything should work fine.