# AMD Radeon r9: weird results using GPU compute

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

[image: Screenshot of render result]

hello so i'm having weird results using gpu compute on my blender(v.2.77 on steam) and when i render my project it comes out like this, also tried just using the cpu(which comes out how it should) any ideas on how to fix this or something i could do? simple scene just to test it using a plane and a cube with camera and sun, default cycles setup, windows 10 pro, amd radeon r9 280 gpu(lastest drivers), rendered using default settings at 720p 100% resolution

Comment: There's not nearly enough information to be able to help you. What is are your system specs, what graphics card do you have? How are you rendering this, what ware your render settings, what is your scene like? Please update your answer to add more information

Comment: What kind of GPU are you using?

Comment: Ist this an ATI gpu?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55204/gpu-render-turning-out-grey-when-using-certain-materials. @cegaton seems to be, because as is stated "amd radeon r9 280 gpu". This could be some problem refering to AMD drivers.

Comment: Have in mind that AMD GPU support is currently experimental and not as mature and well supported as CUDA, so expect some problems and disabled features

Comment: after reading through the related topic post my @Mr Zak, going back to to an older driver sorted the issue out for me using the 16.4.2 version, thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1):

after reading through the related topic post my @Mr Zak, going back to to an older driver sorted the issue out for me using the 16.4.2 version, thanks for the help guys